# Multiple leads on capacitor?

Tags: capacitor

Beginner question, but at least my Google skills didn't yield any results. Why do some capacitors have 5 terminals? Such as this one

[image]

What are they used for?

Comment: Since your capacitor bears the BC components and Vishay logos, I'm surprised Google didn't at least get you close to: http://www.vishay.com/docs/28346/051053pe.pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Check out this [data sheet](http://vishay.com/docs/28346/051053pe.pdf) of the Vishay capacitors that look alike the one you showed. It seems the extra pins are for mounting, since it's a big capacitor.

Comment: +1 ; the exact datasheet for this line of Vishay capacitors is http://www.vishay.com/docs/28346/051053pe.pdf , link provided by EM Fields - it'd be nice if the answer would include that instead of TDK, since it is, in fact, Vishay's one.

Comment: @vaxquis You are right, I edited accordingly. I didn't notice the Vishay brand on the photo the first time, although I came accorss that data sheet as well and selected the TDK, for I liked the detailed pinout drawings.

Comment: @Sergio: Note Fig. 7 and 8 on the Vishay data sheet.

Answer (score 5):

This could very well be multiple capacitors in one package, probably with a shared negative (-). The legend states "1 = 220 uF". Are there also markings like "2 = xyz uF", and are the connections by any chance marked -, 1, 2, etc?

Comment: I don't have one, I was just looking at auctions on a local site and started to wonder. Thank you for educating a beginner, I think it probably is that, I will accept the answer if the time limit comes :)

Answer (score 2):

For completeness, [motor "capacitors"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motor_capacitor) are often more than one actual capacitor bundled into a single package, and thus have more than two leads.  A very common example is the start/run capacitor usually found in air-conditioning units.

I don't think your image is one of these though.